# Should I use bones or shape keys to control the movements of a cat models ear?

Tags: rigging, bones, shape-keys

I'm not sure if this is where you ask questions like this, but I'm trying to rig a cat and am wondering if it would be better to use shape keys to control its ear movements or bones? Any thoughts?

Also, if this isn't where I ask questions like this, please let me know where to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on what you want to do with the model after it was rigged. If it's going to be used in a game engine then you will want to see if it can support exported shape keys. If it will stay in Blender then shape keys will be fine. 
You can always set up both then see which works best and is easiest to do for future work.

Comment: That's a good idea, I will try both out and see how it goes. Thanks for the info about games and shape keys, the rigs not for a game but an animation, either way, it's a good tidbit to remember. :)

Comment: Shape keys are great, but every vertex will be moving only in a straight line, from basis shape to target shape, so sometimes are not a good choice: it all depends of the kind of movement you need.